# Get the Latest Value or the Last Value in Range in google sheet using .gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the latest or last cell value in range BB

`var content2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E1").getRange("B:B"); var tcontent2 = content2.getValue();`

this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var tcontent2 = content2.getValue();
```

#### To:

```
var tcontent2 = content2.getValues().flat().filter(b => b.toString()).pop();
```

- In this modification, the value of the last row of the cells which have the values is retrieved.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

### Added:

From the following your replying,

> i got this error 11:11:06 AM Error Exception: Argument too large: subject

Unfortunately, I cannot understand about this. So in your situation, how about reducing the range as follows?

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E1");
var values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var tcontent2 = values.flat().filter(b => b.toString()).pop();
```

Comment: thanks, where do you get to know this stuff?,

Comment: i mean how do you able to know this can you send me a link where i can study these codes and their application

Comment: @john foreign PH Thank you for replying. In my proposed script, `content2.getValues()` returns all values from the range ("B:B"). And, the retrieved value is flatten with `flat`. The empty values are removed from the flatten array using `filter`. And, then, the last element of the array is retrieved using `pop`. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: i got this error 11:11:06 AM Error 
Exception: Argument too large: subject

Comment: @john foreign PH Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from replying, I proposed another modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize again.

Comment: ow it run, im sorry my mistake, thank you very much

Comment: @john foreign PH Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.